# BCrypt in Spring gives different hash then online tools

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bcrypt

I'm using BCrypt in Spring and it's giving me different hashes then some online tools are using like https://bcrypt-generator.com/

Any ideas why?

I've tried setting the strength to 12 in Spring and on the bcrypt-generator.com setting rounds to 12 and it did not work.

```
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12));
    provider.setUserDetailsService(bettingBotUserDetailsService);
```

For the raw password *"admin"* I get these results:

bcrypt-generator.com with 12 rounds:

```
$2y$12$15h6Idq/TwfcuJu6H1VXie/ao7P4AKlLgIrC5yxbwlEUdJjx9Sl5S
```

Spring (captured from debug mode):

```
$2a$10$ED5wQChpxzagbvhlqEqD2.iIdIKv9ddvJcX0WKrQzSOckgc3RHFLW
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*BCrypt generates the different salt for the same Input*. [Bcrypt Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)

BCrypt returns a different hash each time because it incorporates a different random value into the hash. This is known as a *"salt"*. It prevents people from attacking your hashed passwords with a `"rainbow table"`, a pre-generated table mapping password hashes back to their passwords. The salt means that instead of there being one hash for a password, there's `2^16` of them.

We can check the hashed with normal string as follow

```
Boolean isMatch = passwordEncoder().matches(currentPassword,dbPassword);

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: Hello @sasaFajkovic, Please accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was just checking about it even more today. So basically there is no way to add a hashed password into the database using some online generators? When creating some test users I need to run the application in debug mode, grab the generated hash and insert it into the database.

Comment: No, we have to generate the password into the application while creating user generate the password using PasswordEncoder and save it to the db